# django update view adds a record instead of replacing the updated one

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

this is my Django view for the update form
 views.py

```py
def updatebc(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(BaseCase, pk=pk)
    instance.base_case_name
    bcform = BaseCaseForm(request.POST or None,instance=instance)
    if bcform.is_valid():
        instance = bcform.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
    context = {
        'bcform':bcform,
    }
    return render(request, 'update.html', context)
```

and here is my models.py

```py
class BaseCase(models.Model):
    base_case_name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=255)
    version = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    default = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'base_case'
```

when I try to update a record I actually add one instead of replacing it !

Comment: Why have you set a CharField as the primary key?

Comment: I'm not allowed to make changes on the database schema :/

Comment: where is models.py ?

Comment: i didn't get your question? i've mentioned models.py in my question  above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#primary-key):

> The primary key field is read-only. If you change the value of the primary key on an existing object and then save it, a new object will be created alongside the old one.

You are changing the primary key field `base_case_name`, so instead of updating the instance, django will create a new one.

Comment: totally true because when i change something else instead of the base_case_name it works fine, is there any alternative to force it ?

Comment: @MehdiSelbi If you want to prevent users from changing the primary-key field, you can simply `exclude` it in the form.

Answer (score 2):

```
def updatebc(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(BaseCase, pk=pk)
    instance.base_case_name
    bcform = BaseCaseForm(request.POST or None,instance=instance)
    if bcform.is_valid():
        instance = bcform.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
    context = {
        'bcform':bcform,
        'instance': instance,
    }
    return render(request, 'update.html', context)
```

Pass instance also to your template and see

Comment: instance as a context doesn't change anything in my case the problem is in the primary key as mentioned above